# Minimizing a function to find unknown parameters

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have

```
x=["lists of numbers"]
events=["lists of numbers"]
```

I want to minimize a function having 'a' and 'b' as parameters

```
def f(a,b):
    for i in range(0,71):
        s=0.0
        sum1=((events[i]-x[i]**(a+b*np.log(x[i]))**2)/np.sqrt(events[i]))
        s=s+sum1
```

I want to get the values a and b

How can I minimize f?

Comment: `x = (y-x^a)^b` is not a function. It is not clear to me what is to be minimized. The objective should be something like `f(a,b)`. I suspect you want a least squares solution?

Comment: please can you see the edited question? I mentioned in detail now

Comment: This is a strange function. You may want to check that again.

Comment: I have the same problem as this, he wants to find the best values a and b based on the sum of all terms after looping he will get the sum so how can we optimize this f(a,b) function